# Where these Listener.ora and TNSnames.ora files are present in Windows 10

Tags: oracle, networking, adapter, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbconnection

I have downloaded the Oracle SQL developer in Windows 10.
Trying to create the DB connection in oracle SQL developer.But don't know the username and password.
Google suggested to check username and password in "Listener.ora" and "TNSnames.ora" file but i couldn't find no where in my system. In Windows 10 where these files are present Or how can I get the username,password,port_no to create the new connection

Comment: Have you installed client ?

Comment: "Oracle SQL developer" is a CLIENT software. You need the actual database installed in your machine in order to use it. Download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html After installing the database server you will be able to connect to it with sql developer.

Answer (score 1):

These files are mostly user by server, or OCI drivers(C,C++,ODBC based apps). JDBC drivers (Java based  applications) do not rely on them. Although they can also user them.

These files are usually found in a directory specified by env. variable `%TNS_ADMIN%` or `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`.